# Laravel flash session truncates session

Tags: laravel, session

I am using db session in `Laravel 5.2`. While passing data to view I am using flash session. Session gets destroyed in below case.

```
        $data = $currentStockTable::select('*')->where('id',$current_id)->first();
        Session::flash('preview', $data->preview);
        Session::flash('content', $data->content);
        Session::flash('author', $data->author);
```

on view

```
<textarea class="ckeditor form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="10">{{ Session::has('content') ? Session::get('content') : '' }}</textarea>
```

The content data is having string and image encoded data. This content data results into destroy session (logged out user). When I dont pass content data (or pass only string) then it works correctly.

This issue is not coming on dev environment. Did I missed any configuration parameter for live ?

Session config in session.php

```
'driver' =>  env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'lifetime' => 720,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => 'laravel_session_admin',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => true,
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you show your session config? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Using laravel 5.2  and Session config settings : 

'driver' =>  env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'lifetime' => 720,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => 'laravel_session_admin',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => true,

Comment: Do you have any values in your `.env` that overrides these?

Comment: No values in .env file